# Run task when show notification

Tags: android, background, notifications, task

(sorry for my English)

I need help with my first program, which i must make to friday to pass the course on study...

I'm trying to create an application that will display a notification with a description from the table to which the reminders are added. I have a problem with the mechanism of getting next description to display. I made a description of the application after the notification was displayed. Unfortunately, this does not work when the application is closed.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ScheduleNotification.completeWakefulIntent(intent);

    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    descToShow = d1;

    DataBaseHandler dbh = new DataBaseHandler(context);
    dbh.open();
    dbh.DeleteRow(descToShow);
    dbh.close();


    Toast.makeText(context, descToShow, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    //notification
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon);
    builder.setContentTitle(descToShow);
    builder.setContentText(descToShow); //--description event--
    builder.setAutoCancel(false).build();

    //from android dev:
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);

    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);

    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent( 0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );
    builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    mNotificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
    PendingIntent notifyPIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(), 0);
    builder.setContentIntent(notifyPIntent);
}
```

Any ideas ?

all code on my github: https://github.com/azernax/dForget

Comment: Don't use separate `SharedPreferences` for every value - one can hold them all. Related values should be stored in one file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you use static fields from your `MainActivity` when the `MainActivity` isn't in memory (so you get default values instead of those set in `onCreate()`). The correct solution is to load data again (in your case from `SharedPreferences`).

I hope this helps you. Comment if you have any questions

Comment: Thanks for help resolve my problem with SharedPreferences. But I have new problem :( for example when I create 2 notification, first noti don't display, just second notification display in infinite loop... can you help me ? Current code is on my github.

Comment: You need to set a notification ID in `NotificationBuilder` - in your case, having IDs 1, 2 and 3 for d1, d2 and d3 would be a reasonable idea